# NodeJS Mysql - Connection not being released

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

It seems that MySQL pool isn't releasing connection from my NodeJS app. When looking at the server processes from mysql, connections are established but not released.

The app is crashing with the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined`. From my understanding, this is because i've exceeded connections limit.

To note, I'm using Heroku MySQL plugin and have a limit of 10 connections for testing. I've added connectionLimit to end of my .env DB_URL to try to limit my connections in the pool.

In my .env file, the link is formatted as such:
`DEV_DB_URL=mysql://user:pass@host:3306/db_name?connectionLimit=5`

The db.js file:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var dbURL = process.env.PRODUCTION === 'true'
  ? process.env.LIVE_DB_URL
  : process.env.DEV_DB_URL;

var dbConnection = function dbConnection( sql, values, next){

  // It means that the values hasn't been passed
  if (arguments.length === 2){
    next = values;
    values = null;
  }

  var pool = mysql.createPool(dbURL);
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    connection.query(sql, values, function(err) {

      connection.release();

      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }

      // Execute the callback
      next.apply(this, arguments);
    });
  });
};


module.exports = dbConnection;
```

My controller that uses the db.js file looks like this:

```
var DB = require('../services/db');
exports.updateReporting = function(req, res){
  var body = req.body;
  var sentStatus = body.edc;


  if( sentStatus === 'pass'){
    res.status(200)
      .send({
        message: 'EDC is all good.'
      })
  }


  if( sentStatus === 'fail'){
    var dateTime = require('node-datetime');
    var dt = dateTime.create();
    var curTimestamp = dt.format('Y-m-d H:M:S');

    var storeId = body.store_id
      .substring('Addr1='.length);
    var fileTimestamp = body.file_ts;

    var data = {
      status: sentStatus,
      store_id: storeId,
      file_ts: fileTimestamp,
      current_ts: curTimestamp
    };


    DB('INSERT INTO edc_reporting SET ?', data, function( err, row ){
      if (err) throw err;
    });

    res.status(200)
      .send({
        message: 'Message recorded.'
      })
  }

};
```

As i'm new to Node, i'm not sure if my `connection.release()` is in the wrong place and not executed because of call back?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was really silly mistake.

In the `db.js` file, I had `var pool = mysql.createPool(dbURL);` *inside* the exported function; this is wrong.

Every time there was a request, the connection would be re-created and a new pool started. To solve the issue, I moved the creation of the pool outside the dbConnection function, hence, only 1 pool was created and connecting was started.

Answer (score 0):

Despite declaring the pool outside the export function and releasing connection with connection.release() it didnot work for me. Using pool.query instead of connection.query worked perfectly fine it releases connection automatically everytime.